# Using exact percentages and font-size:0 to make grids that fit perfectly?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, whitespace

I'm trying to work with grids which are whole numbers, that perfectly match up, e.g 20% for 5 menu items would fill 100%.

I have the following code:

```
#menu-primary-navigation li{display:inline-block;font-size:0;width:20%;}
#menu-primary-navigation li a{font-size:22px;}
```

I understand the issue of *whitespace* between `ul li` elements that means 20% elements will not fit into 100% due to the white space in between each element. However I thought I had got around this issue by making `font-size:0;` where the elements sit and then only setting the font size inside the element.

Yet you can see in my JSFiddle that the five menu items still do not fit perfectly to 100% of the container.

In my example, the width is `600px` and each element is `20%`. I can see from inspecting the elements that they are all equal to `120px`. Well `120 x 5 = 600`, so why does the last element always fall to the next line?

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul id="menu-primary-navigation" class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="http://localhost/esk/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="http://localhost/esk/knitting/">Tutorials</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a>Logo</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="http://localhost/esk/projects/">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="http://localhost/esk/articles/">Articles</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/franhaselden/kq9o4t0v/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/kq9o4t0v/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `display: inline-block;` is notoriously problematic in this situation. You could consider using `display: table-cell;` achieve the same result with less hassle.

HTML can remain the same, but try this CSS:

```
.wrapper{width:600px;}
ul,li{padding:0;margin:0;}
/* needed for use with display: table-cell; */
.menu{ display: table; width: 100%; }
/* changed to table-cell */
#menu-primary-navigation li{display:table-cell; text-align: center;}
#menu-primary-navigation li a{font-size:22px;}
```

However as I am supposed to be answering the question the part you went wrong is you need to set the font size on the parent i.e the `ul` in order to effect the white-space. Do note however, I think certain versions of IE will not like `font-size: 0;`

CSS:

```
.wrapper{width:600px;}
/* you need it set on the parent */
ul,li{padding:0;margin:0; font-size: 0; }
#menu-primary-navigation li{display: inline-block; width: 20%; text-align: center;}
#menu-primary-navigation li a{font-size:22px;}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Explained the issue and added advice for a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `font-size:0` on the li tag to remove whitespace. However the li's are contained in the ul, so you need to set the font-size there.

In your jsfiddle the issue is resolved by setting

`.wrapper{width:600px;}
ul,li{padding:0;margin:0;font-size:0}`